# How do I call a static bool method in main.m

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, static, boolean

This is Objective-C, in Xcode for the iPhone.

I have a method in main.m:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

//I want to call the method here//

int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
[pool release];
return retVal;
}

static BOOL do_it_all () {
//code here//
}
```

How do I call the do_it_all method from main.m?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call it normally, so long as you've already declared the function before you call it. Either move the function definition above `main()` or add the following line above:

```
static BOOL do_it_all ();
```

Personally, I think the former is easier, but if you have circular dependencies between functions, it can be impossible to resolve without function prototypes.

When you do add function prototypes in C/Objective-C/etc. they are frequently in a header (`.h`) file, but if everything is in main.m this is probably overkill.

Comment: I did have circular dependencies.  This information has been very helpful.  Thank you.

Working in main.m seems to be jus a little bit different than standard .h/.m files.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
do_it_all();
```

It's just an ordinary C function call. But you will either need to move the declaration of `do_it_all` before `main`, or forward declare it; otherwise, `main` won't know what you're talking about.

Comment: How do I forward declare it.  I thought you could only forward declare a class.

Comment: Forward declaration of an Objective-C class (with `@class`) is different. In this case we're talking about a function prototype.